# Django data retrieval performance

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

I have four models:

**User** -> Has One Profile

**Profile** -> Has one Dweller

**Dweller** -> Belongs to many Profiles

**Database** -> Belongs to one Dweller

Given a **User** object, I want to retrieve the **Database** object that indirectly belongs to the **User** object.

I allready can do this following my database schema:

```
profile = user.profile
dweller = profile.dweller
database = Database.objects.get(dweller_id=dweller.id)
```

It's working properly but Im wondering if is this the most elegant and better performance way, I mean, when python executes **profile = user.profile** did the profile object comes from the database query with all the dweller data too ( via JOIN ), or the dweller data is retrieved only when python executes the **dweller = profile.dweller** code line ( with another JOIN )?

My concerns is if each code line submits a new query to Database, would be better if I could condense this query with, I dont know, with a QuerySet? And if is this the case, how can I do this? Would this actually improve performance? The connection handshaking of multiples sequential queries could slows my overall process?

Django newbie here, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code will perform 3 separate queries for `profile`, `dweller` and `database`. If you don't need the other models, you can reduce this to a single query with several `JOIN`s:

```
database = Database.objects.get(dweller__profile__user=user)
```

This is explained in more detail in the docs on [lookups that span relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships).

Comment: That was exactlly what i needed @knbk . You got my point of view . Really thank you.